# how to recreate old commits that got missing and unreachable at repository move

Tags: git, clone, commit, recover

I have moved from gitorious to gitlab and when doing the first push to gitlab, forgot to also push all my tags.

In the old repository, some commits were only reachable due to them having a tag at their commit chain tip. Since the new repo didn't get tags pushed, these commits are now unreachable -- in fact, they are not even present in my local or new remote repository anymore (probably gc'ed).
I was hoping I could just somehow recover these commits without messing with any history. Here's the situation:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F <-- master today
     \                
      X---Y---Z       
              ^       
              lost tag
```

I still have the old local repository on my disk (linked with a now unavailable gitorious remote) together with the commits X Y Z which I'd like to push to the new repo.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can't you simply add the GitLab repo as a remote to your local repository and push again, including all of the tags?

Comment: @nwinkler: Yes, I've thought about something like this but I'm a bit scared of messing up my public remote when pushing to it from a "deprecated" local repo. If you think this is the solution, I would be very thankful if you could guide me through the commands necessary (especially the push command once I've added the new repo as remote for the old local). I guess it's just something like git push <Z> --tags?

Comment: Have you made any commits in the new location (GitLab) that are not in the old local repo?

Comment: @nwinkler: Yes, many in different branches and on master itself.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed in this case, sorry. You might have to pull these changes into your local repo first and then push from there. Make sure you have a backup of the local repo in a safe location in case it gets messed up during the merge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problem according to *nwinkler*'s suggestion:

In my old local repo, I've changed the remote to the new repo and pushed all tags:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin [new repo URL]
git push --tags
```

(I think I could've used `set-url` instead but I didn't know that from the top of my head.)

Interestingly, this didn't push the "lost tag" even though it existed in the old local repo. I had to create a temporary branch on the locally existing tag and push it

```
git checkout <lost-tag-which-exists-in-old-local>
git checkout -b temp-resurrect
git push -u origin temp-resurrect
git branch -d temp-resurrect
git push origin --delete temp-resurrect
```

After this I could see the commits X Y Z and the tag in the new remote repository (web interface) and pull the tag and commits to the new local repo.

I'll leave this question open for now, in case someone finds a better solution to the problem.